# Nvidia flash.sh file not found in ubuntu 18

Tags: nvidia-jetson

I want to create an image from nvidia jetson tx2, in several places (like https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php?title=Cloning_TX2) talk about **flash.sh** file to perform the task but I cannot found it, also I search using `find / -iname flash.sh`  and nothing. Where can I find this file? Do I need install something eles?

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, Jetpack 4.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download L4T Driver Package (BSP) driver from: https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/linux-tegra and download, be sure to dowload the correct version for your JetPach, for **4.5.1** check this:

https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/l4t/r32_release_v5.1/r32_release_v5.1/t186/tegra186_linux_r32.5.1_aarch64.tbz2

Answer (score 1):

Try to download this
https://gist.github.com/Davidnet/013ceb704ebdc7ebd728e059f90fca80

Put it in your path.

Run

```
./flash.sh
```

Comment: sorry, this file could work with certain version, not for me, I found that I need to download the L4T driver for the right JetPack version, thank you anyway